# Assigning pre-allocated array to pointer in class constructor C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, scientific-computing

I am working on a project for my advanced CFD class, in which we have to solve the heat equation over a curvilinear mesh. I am trying to create an object which will store all of my data, to allow me to visualize it easily later on. This object is created using a class called Solution. Solution contains 8 public variables, all of which are double precision, *x, *y, *u, *v, *T, nx, ny and N, where x and y store the coordinates for each point, u and v the velocities for each point, T stores the temperature for each point, nx and ny store the number of grid points in the x and y direction, and finally N stores the total number of grid points. I have 3 constructors, the first of which initializes the object with all null pointers or values of 0.

```
Solution::Solution() : X(nullptr), Y(nullptr), u(nullptr), v(nullptr), T(nullptr), nx(0), ny(0), N(0)
```

The second constructor takes a value for nx and ny, calculates the number of points, allocates memory for each of the arrays, and initializes their values to 0.

```
// Constructor to initialize solution struct with 0 values
Solution::Solution(unsigned long iNx, unsigned long iNy) : X(nullptr), Y(nullptr), u(nullptr), v(nullptr), T(nullptr), nx(iNx), ny(iNy)
{
    N = nx * ny; // Total number of grid points

    // Allocate memory for solution variables
    O.alloc1D(&X, N);
    O.alloc1D(&Y, N);
    O.alloc1D(&u, N);
    O.alloc1D(&v, N);
    O.alloc1D(&T, N);

    // Initialize variables values to 0
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        X[i] = 0.0;
        Y[i] = 0.0;
        u[i] = 0.0;
        v[i] = 0.0;
        T[i] = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Where I am having trouble is for my 3rd constructor, in which I hope to create the object using pre-defined arrays.

```
// Constructor to initialize solution struct using vectors that already exist
Solution::Solution(unsigned long iNx, unsigned long iNy, double *iX, double *iY, double *iu, double *iv, double *iT) :
                   X(iX), Y(iY), u(iu), v(iv), T(iT), nx(iNx), ny(iNy)
```

I am having issues figuring out how to assign the arrays to these values. Looking at just X, if I try to implement an array

```
double x[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
```

for X in the constructor it gives me an error as it cannot assign a double to double*. If I try to write

```
double *x[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
```

it gives me an error as it cannot assign double to double* for each value in the array. If I try

```
double *x;
double x1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

x = &x1;
```

it gives me an error because it cannot convert double(*)[4] to double in initialization.  I feel like there is an easy solution to let me construct my Solution object with arrays that are already defined, but I'm getting stuck. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The solution to the compilation error is to write `x = x1;` or `x = &x1[0];`. Although I have a strong suspicion you will run into other issues later on if you are doing things like these

Comment: Why not make `X`, `Y` etc. `std::vector<double>`s instead of `double*`s? It'll save you a lot of hassle dealing with manual memory management so that you can concentrate on the _real_ problem.

Comment: I will try writing it as a vector rather than a double. I am new to c++, and in our previous CFD class we were provided data structures that worked similar to what I have written, which is what I was trying to imitate. I'll look into vectors rather than double arrays thank you.

Comment: You declare your member variable `X` as `std::vector<double> X;` and in the member initializer list of your class: `Solution::Solution(unsigned long iNx, unsigned long iNy) : X(iNx * iNy) {}` ... done. Another upside of using `std::vector<double>` is that you can copy the whole thing when needed. `std::vector<double> a_copy = X;` makes `a_copy` contain exactly the same amount of elements as `X` and they will have the same values as in `X` too.

Comment: think about: what do you want the computer to do? you want it to put 1.0 in x[0] and 2.0 in x[1] and 3.0 in x[2] and 4.0 in x[3], right? You can write that. That's the easy solution. If you want it to be *shorter* there are probably ways to make it shorter.

Comment: `double *x[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};` --> `#include <vector> #include <numeric>...std::vector<double> x(4); std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), 1.0);`